# secondary navigation per page

Tags: theming, navigation

I created a secondary navigation that I display with $secondary_menu in page.tpl.php. It seems to work fine, however, it displays on every page now and I of course don't want that, it should only show on a specific page (where I have a secondary navigation). Now in order to achieve this, am I creating a special page template for the page where I want to show the links or can I somehow set on which pages my secondary navigation should show up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your secondary menu will be available as a block.

Go to `/admin/structure/block`, place the block in the page region you wish to use, and set it to display only on the pages you wish to have it on.

This is much easier than trying to set up specialized templates.